# pip install editable error: module not found setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a package that I have installed on other machines many times but on my Mac I am getting a strang error.  I have tried doing this in a conda environment and in a virtual environment, always getting the same error below.

Note that:

- I can open a python shell and import setuptools without issue.
- The install works without -e
- The command it lists as having failed I can run fine manually.
- I have upgraded setuptools via pip

```
/Users/eric/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mypkg-3XmClfyY-py3.9/bin/pip install -e ~/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg
Obtaining file:///Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: loguru<0.6.0,>=0.5.3 in /Users/eric/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mypkg-3XmClfyY-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from mypkg==0.1.0) (0.5.3)
Installing collected packages: mypkg
  Running setup.py develop for mypkg
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/eric/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mypkg-3XmClfyY-py3.9/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: /Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '/Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/setup.py'; __file__='/Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/setup.py';f = getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('from setuptools import setup; setup()');code = f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
                                                  │                                                                                                                                                                            │                             └ <module 'io' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/io.py'>
                                                  │                                                                                                                                                                            └ <module 'os' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py'>
                                                  └ <module 'sys' (built-in)>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/eric/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mypkg-3XmClfyY-py3.9/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/Users/eric/Documents/MyDir/repo/mypkg/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `pip uninstall setuptools` ?

Comment: Did you pip install inside the virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in the pyproject.toml.  I didn't realize that pip was reading that (seems obvious now though).

The issue was this from when I was configuring poetry:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Comment: Thanks, this was also my case!!

Answer (score -2):

Your setup.py file needs setuptools. Some Python packages used to use distutils for distribution, but most now use setuptools, a more complete package. Here is a question about the differences between them.

To install setuptools on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

For an older version of Python (Python 2.x):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

And then check your virtualenv.